# Dynamic parameters in relationship for different date formats

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to join two tables by date. The problem is that the date column is grouped by various formats, depending on a parameter from the API.

For example, let's say that I join `payments` and `payment_details` tables:

**payments:**

```
id | date
1    2020-01-31
```

**payment_details:**

```
id | date       | detail
1    2020-01-31   aaa
```

**Query:**

```
$results = Payment::with(['payment_details' => function ($q) { 
  $q->addSelect('detail');
}])->get();
```

**Payment.php:**

```
public function payment_details()
{
  return $this->hasMany(PaymentDetail::class, 'date', 'date');
}
```

**Resulting query:**

```
select * from payment_details where payment_details.date in ('2020-01-31');
```

This is perfectly fine and gives correct results, because the relationship is between normal values in two tables. But when I want to group by `date` column by year:

**Query:**

```
$results = Payment::with(['payment_details' => function ($q) { 
  $q->addSelect('detail')
}])
->groupBy([DB::raw('YEAR(date)')])
->get();
```

**Resulting query:**

```
select * from payment_details where payment_details.date in ('2020');
```

Which is not correct, because the resulting relationship query is always `where payment_details.date`, so it will join the tables always before any `GROUP BY` that I use. I was thinking about using an alias, but they don't work in `where` statements.

So even if my query will be:

**Query:**

```
$results = Payment::with(['payment_details' => function ($q) { 
  $q->addSelect('detail')
    ->groupBy('YEAR(date)'); // here
}])->get();
```

The result is:

**Resulting query:**

```
select * from payment_details where payment_details.date in ('2020') group by YEAR(date);
```

Which is still wrong - because the relationship comes before `group by`. How can I solve this?

A perfect solution would be:

**Resulting query:**

```
select * from payment_details where YEAR(payment_details.date) in ('2020') group by YEAR(date);
```

But seems like I cannot use functions in foreign key parameters of relationship functions like this:

**Payment.php:**

```
public function payment_details()
{
  return $this->hasMany(PaymentDetail::class, 'YEAR(date)', 'date');
}
```

As it will give me `1=0` output.

Comment: *Resulting query: `select * from payment_details where payment_details.date in ('2020');`* You must obtain `Resulting query:
select * from payment_details where YEAR(payment_details.date) in ('2020');` *A perfect solution would be* Grouping makes no sense woth `SELECT *` and no aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is you need to select the `date` out, so laravel
 can combine the `payment_details` relationship with payments:

```php
$years = ["2020"];

$results = Payment::with(['payment_details' => function ($q) use ($years) { 
  $q->addSelect('detail','date')
    ->whereIn(DB::raw("YEAR(payment_details.date)"), $years)
    ->groupBy('YEAR(date)');
}])->get();
```

---

I think something wrong with your relationship.

If you use `date` to connect them, then the `payment_details` will have the same year with `payments`. So you don't need to filter the `year`.

I think you need to create an `payment_id` in `payment_details`, so your relationship in Payment.php will be like this:

```php
public function payment_details()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PaymentDetail::class, 'payment_id', 'id');
}
```

And you can use accessor to get the the `payment_details` which year is as same as `payment`:

```php
protected $appends =['year_payment_details'];

public function getYearPaymentDetailsAttributes()
{
    return $this->payment_details()
                ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(payment_details.date)'), (new \Carbon\Carbon($this->date))->format('Y'))
                ->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(payment_details.date)'))->get();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but `$years = ["2020"];` is what I want to join on from the payments table, not the hardcoded array.

Comment: @khernik do u mean that u want to with the same year's details, including the same year diff date.

Comment: `select date from payment_details where YEAR(payment_details.date) in ('2020') group by YEAR(date);` I want to have a query like this, but where dates are fetched from payments table automatically.

Comment: @khernik each payment can have many payment_details, so if dates are fetched from payments, then the date must only one.

Comment: @khernik what's the relationship between payment's and payment_details? I think you need to add payment_id in payment_details.